# How to invalidate all Redux RTK queries when special event dispatched (socket IO message)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, redux, rtk-query

I want to synchronize SPA react application for all users (several tabs, several users). I wrote a simple react hook which listens for specific socket IO message and updates state variable upon a message called `useGetAllEmployeesQuery`:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export function useRefetchOnMessage (messageType) {
  const [needRefetch, setNeedRefetch] = useState()

  if (!window.io.socket) {
    return
  }

  function handleMessage (e) {
    setNeedRefetch(Date.now())
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.io.socket.on(messageType, handleMessage)

    return () => {
      window.io.socket.off(messageType, handleMessage)
    }
  }, [])

  return needRefetch
}
```

When this event is dispatched I simply call RTK `refetch()` method.

```js
const employees = useGetAllEmployeesQuery(officeId)

const needRefreshEmployees = useRefetchOnMessage('employees changed')

useEffect(() => {
  if (!needRefreshEmployees) return

  employees.refetch()
}, [needRefreshEmployees])
```

As a result we need to call it everywhere in application, imagine we have 5 components using employees query, we need to call `refetch` in all of them. And many queries could run when it's enough to run them once. (invalidate once)

Is it possible to subscribe for any kind of such events in Redux RTK query configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger subscribed queries to *re*-query by invalidating their tags.

See [invalidateTags](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#invalidatetags): A Redux action creator that can be used to manually invalidate cache tags for [automated re-fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching).

Assuming the `getAllEmployees` endpoint is providing a tag, e.g. `"employees"`, you can dispatch an action to invalidate this tag and trigger the `useGetAllEmployeesQuery` hook to refetch data.

```js
const api = createApi({
  ...
  endpoints: builder => ({
    ...
    getAllEmployees: builder.query({
      query: ......,
      ...
      providesTags: ["employees"],
    }),
    ...
  }),
});
```

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import api from '../path/to/apiSlice';

export function useRefetchOnMessage (messageType = "", tags = []) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMessage = () => {
      dispatch(api.util.invalidateTags(tags));
    };

    window.io?.socket?.on(messageType, handleMessage);

    return () => {
      window.io?.socket?.off(messageType, handleMessage);
    }
  }, [messageType, tags]);
}
```

The UI code need only call the hooks, passing the `"employees"` tag to the `useRefetchOnMessage` hook.

```js
const employees = useGetAllEmployeesQuery(officeId);
useRefetchOnMessage('employees changed', ["employees"]);
```

Comment: Tx, looks like exactly what I was looking for, will try when I'm back to my laptop and let you know.

Comment: @Rantiev Sure thing, I'm always around.

Comment: Tx, it does work! 

But additionally I created one function where I set up this 'useRefetchOnMessage' for all slices needed to refetch on socket messages. So we setup it in one place instead of useRefetch under every subscription. 

That was my goal. Thank you.

Comment: @Rantiev Great to hear! I wanted to point you also in the direction of [custom listener middlware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware) as a means of establishing a socket instance and listening (*the socket*) for events and dispatching the tag invalidation action. It's a bit of a more advanced Redux concept, but would effectively leave you with a single code unit that does what you want and is decoupled from the UI.